# Error when creating a procedure with some parameters of input, and insert later in DB, after a validation in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My problem is this, I am trying to create a procedure that receives input parameters and check if the data exists or not, to be able to insert in one table or another.
I have tried in different ways and I can not find the error that appears in the syntax of the declaration.

Please I need help.

A thousand thanks in advance.

/ * Next I show the code of the procedure * /

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMensaje(IN pNOMBRE varchar(50), IN pTLFN varchar(9), IN pEMAIL varchar(50), IN pASN varchar(15), IN pMSG varchar(500))

BEGIN

    /*declare valiable*/
    DECLARE vIDCLI int;

/*THESE OPTIONS I HAVE ALSO TESTED*/
/*SET vIDCLI = (select id_cliente from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL);*/
/*select id_cliente into vIDCLI from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL;*/

/* DECLARE vAUX varchar(50)*/ 
/* SET vAUX = (select email from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL);*/
/* select email into vAUX from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL; */

/* IF (vAUX <=> NULL) THEN  */

    /*check if the pEMAIL parameter exists*/
    IF EXISTS (select id_cliente from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL) THEN

    /*retrieve the ID and assign it to the variable*/
    select id_cliente into vIDCLI from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL;

        /*insert in BD menssage table*/
        INSERT INTO `tb_msg`(`asn`, `msg`, `id_cli`) VALUES ('pASN','pMSG','vIDCLI');

    ELSE
        /*insert new cliente*/
        INSERT INTO `tb_cliente`(`nombre`, `tlfn`, `email`) 
                        VALUES ('pNOMBRE','pTLFN','pEMAIL');

        /*recovernew IdCli*/
        SET vIDCLI = (select id_cliente from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL);

        /*insert in message table*/
        INSERT INTO `tb_msg`(`asn`, `msg`, `id_cli`) VALUES ('pASN','pMSG',vIDCLI);
    END IF;
END; //

DELIMITER //
```

MySQL has said:

> 1064 -  Something is wrong in its syntax near 'IF EXISTS (select id_cliente from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL) THEN' on line 25

Comment: Please update your title to be in English please

Comment: Ok It's done, sorry

Comment: @Miguel you cannot use IF Exists like that. My suggestion is to write the select separately first, and get the result `into` a variable and then check on the variable using `if`

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not a DB developer, you probably could do like this (this is just an idea, exact syntax may differ!):

```
select count(id_cliente) into cnt_clients from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL;
IF cnt_clients > 0 /* EXISTS case */
...
ELSE /* NOT EXISTS case */
```

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot use `IF EXISTS` inside a stored procedure, as you were attempting to do so.
- At the time of declaration of the variable `vIDCLI`, you can set its Default value to `null`
- Now, get the Select results `Into` the variable.
- And, then check if the variable `vIDCLI` `IS NOT NULL` (inside the `if` condition).

Try the following:

```
/*declare variable - default it to null*/
DECLARE vIDCLI int(11) DEFAULT NULL;

select id_cliente into vIDCLI 
from tb_cliente 
where email = pEMAIL;

/*check if the pEMAIL parameter exists*/
IF vIDCLI IS NOT NULL THEN
```

You also have other errors in your stored procedure. After fixing them, this is how your corrected procedure looks like:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE InsertMensaje(IN pNOMBRE varchar(50), IN pTLFN varchar(9), IN pEMAIL varchar(50), IN pASN varchar(15), IN pMSG varchar(500))

BEGIN

    /*declare variable - default it to null*/
    DECLARE vIDCLI int(11) DEFAULT NULL;

   select id_cliente into vIDCLI 
   from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL;

/* DECLARE vAUX varchar(50)*/ 
/* SET vAUX = (select email from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL);*/
/* select email into vAUX from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL; */

/* IF (vAUX <=> NULL) THEN  */

    /*check if the pEMAIL parameter exists*/
    IF vIDCLI IS NOT NULL THEN

        /*insert in BD menssage table*/
        INSERT INTO `tb_msg`(`asn`, `msg`, `id_cli`) VALUES ('pASN','pMSG','vIDCLI');

    ELSE
        /*insert new cliente*/
        INSERT INTO `tb_cliente`(`nombre`, `tlfn`, `email`) 
                        VALUES ('pNOMBRE','pTLFN','pEMAIL');

        /*recovernew IdCli*/
        select id_cliente into vIDCLI 
        from tb_cliente where email = pEMAIL;

        /*insert in message table*/
        INSERT INTO `tb_msg`(`asn`, `msg`, `id_cli`) VALUES ('pASN','pMSG',vIDCLI);
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But still giving an error in the variable that collects from the select

Comment: @Miguel what is the error message. Please give details here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and dedication, but I gave an error on line 25 in the select statement. Finally, the other boy could find the answer. 
It is through this link. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/198985/101069

Comment: @Miguel in english please

Comment: @Miguel what is the code around line no 25 ? can you share your complete stored procedure statement